# How do I debug errors with ActiveAdmin with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, logging, activeadmin

There is a rails application that uses bunch of gems one of which is ActiveAdmin.
Dashboard works OK, but other custom tabs gets a 500 response.
How do I enabled debugging/logging inside ActiveAdmin gem to get to the bottom of this problem?

Corresponding generic question is this: what are the ways to enable debugging on rails apps with multiple gem dependencies?

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Check your development.log file after hitting the custom tab page and see where the error was. The log should give you a stack trace or at least tell you the last controller that was hit. You can use this information to work backwards and find out where you code is breaking.

2) Once you have found the broken spot in the code you can use `raise` or [pry debugger](https://github.com/pry/pry) to inspect variables/methods to help you debug.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a version mismatch between the mongoid interface and the active admin interface.Thanks for all the help.